# How to show thumbnail image from Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I got the thumbnailLink [DoFu](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/y6bj9PRdmvojl4oTsOzyrwml9bOFywPzZ0olStD1_VZgnZ8dgUazJ71vjkKuxPanLXU1rGGcLZaN=s220) of my uploaded public file in Drive by following the [Google Drive API Samples](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) with Javascript. The image can be shown when opening the link on browsers. However, it cannot be shown on HTML image element.

[image]

I also tried to access this image via API key with "GET [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{FILE_ID}?fields=contentHints%2Fthumbnail%2Fimage%2CthumbnailLink&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%7BFILE_ID%7D?fields=contentHints%2Fthumbnail%2Fimage%2CthumbnailLink&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)", and it can return me an object within a thumbnailLink. However, it cannot be shown on image element either.

How can I get the real image source link in order to show it on my web page?

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean with "_it cannot be shown on HTML image element_"? if you open your thumbnail link, the opened page shows the image in `img` element ...

Comment: I meant when I put the thumbnailLink into img element e.g. <img src="{LINK}"/>, the image could not be shown. It seems that the thumbnailLink is not a direct image link.

Comment: Umh ... Please follow the "DoFu"-link you've provided in your question, view the source of the code, and you can see, that the thumbnail is used in the src of an `img` element ...

Comment: that is the special string after "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/, " it is same as the thumbnailLink I retrieve from Drive. It seems not be put in img element directly. The img element shows nothing.

Comment: View the source, and copy the src from there, add where ever you need it, should work. Like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcxcuxam/).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0xooO9Y65w7cUxsSlZNOFFCS00/view?usp=sharing

it cannot be shown directly though. Anything wrong in my browsers?

Comment: That's odd, I can see the image on that same fiddle ...

Comment: Do I need to set up special scopes ?

Comment: @Teemu the link seems be dynamic and is authenticate needed

Answer (score 2):

I finally use this way to solve it. To get thumbnail link with scopes **drive** and **drive.readonly** , and set it to *https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz=w320&id=[fileid]*. It get let user get thumbnail image to private data when logging in.